# Woocommerce custom shop page layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I have fixed all things in Woocommerce plugin as per my requirements, but i am unable to find one solution. Woocommerce default shop page products loop code is like this

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to change this code into this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     // Product Loop Card here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     // Product Loop Card here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     // Product Loop Card here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     // Product Loop Card here
  </div>
  // etc etc etc
</div>
```

Screenshot of what gone wrong
[image]

**Which function/filter/hooks or custom template can do this? Please help me**

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but this is considered a "BAD PRACTICE" in terms of scalability and extendability. Almost all of the wordpress/woocommerce developers follow a standard blueprint (i.e standard html markups, classes, ids etc.). Replacing the standard blueprint of wordpress/woocommerce with your own stuff, will only breaks everything and creates more bugs down the road! Also you won't be able to use other developers plugins/codes because you're not using the standard woocommerce while plugins would hook into the standard markups. It's simply NOT A GOOD IDEA!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the file named

```
content-product.php
```

you can get this here

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates
```

Comment: I have already copied templates folder which is in woocommerce plugin folder to my theme folder and renamed it to "woocommerce". Now, I have to change the file name just or something else?

Comment: You can't change file name otherwise it will not work.
You have to just change code inside the file  OR you can add hook like this

```

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'storefront_product_columns_wrapper', 40 );

function storefront_product_columns_wrapper() {
  echo '<div class="row">';
 }

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the woocommerce/loop folder

inside it has two loop-strat and loop-end files

delete ul, if using bootstrap enter the following code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
```

in loop-end file you need to close divs

```
</div>
</div>
```

now in the content-product file you will create your loop I'm leaving one here of my files example.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >

    <div class="product-grid6">
        <div class="product-image6">

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title');?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="title"><?php do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title');?></h3>
            <div class="price">
                <span>          <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title');?>
</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="" data-tip="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-tip="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-tip="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the follows templates by overridden it into your theme -

`loop/loop-start.php` -> remove `<ul>` tag and replace it with `<div class="row products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">`

`loop/loop-end.php` -> remove `</ul>` tag and replace it with `</div>`

`content-product.php` -> 
1. remove `<li <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>` tag and replace it with `<div class="col-md-4">`
2. remove `</li>` tag and replace it with `</div>`

Comment: I did it but looks ugly, see the screenshot of the result above, I have updated post

Comment: @Zain it seems css issues. First of all make sure that you have got actual structure as per above. If it's okey then you have to fix it via css.